# What are the general steps to setup/run a .js transpiled language in vs code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Specifically, I would like to setup/run Neo, the educational, JavaScript transpiled language that Douglas Crockford introduced/implemented in his book "How JavaScript Works".

He provides specific program files, e.g. 'neo.tokenize.js', 'neo.parser.js', 'neo.codegen.js', 'neo.runtime.js' and other files from the book at https://github.com/douglascrockford/howjavascriptworks.

I would appreciate any guidance and suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: read the Node/JavaScript doc pages for VSC